# Create database if not exist in FuelPHP

Tags: php, database, fuelphp

First of all I don't have any database and I write code in migrations to create database, table and data, I want to check if database not exist then auto create new database have name in db connect and try catch this connect if error.

```
public function up()
{
    try {
        \DBUtil::create_database('database_name', 'utf8_general_ci', true);
        // the true flag adds a IF NOT EXISTS
    } catch(\Database_Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

try code but give error "Unknown database database_name" when I run "php oil refine migrate" in commandline

Can I try catch custom exception this error?

```
1049!

Fuel\Core\Database_Exception [ 1049 ]:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'database_name'
```

Comment: My first thought, is that the exceptions fully qualified name is probably incorrect. Try `catch(Fuel\Core\Database_Exception $e){` what you currently have is telling PHP to look into the root namespace, where things like `DateTime()` exist. Also you can append multiple catches, you can always end off with `catch(\Exception $e) {` which will catch any and all Exceptions that extend PHP's default Exception class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a database is not something that is usually done by migrations as it would tie you in to using the same DB name all the time, if you are deploying multiple sites on the same server or have a similar scenario this becomes a big problem.

It's generally assumed that the database itself has been created as part of the set-up, either manual or automatic, so is available for PHP to connect to.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the user that the app uses to connect to the DB often has restricted permissions for security so it simply might not be possible.